# `ETIMEDOUT` Error when using http.get(...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, error-handling, https

How can I handle `ETIMEDOUT` Error when using `http.get(...)`?
I've tried to wrap `http.get(...)` part with `try-catch` but still failed to catch the error.

Output:

```
Concurrent Response #3 returned a 200
Concurrent Response #2 returned a 200
Concurrent Response #4 returned a 200
Concurrent Response #0 returned a 200
events.js:352
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.94.154.124:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '3.94.154.124',
  port: 80
}
```

Working code:

```
function sendRequest(requestID, cb) {
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 3 + 1)) + 5;
  var request = {
    hostname: "httpbin.org",
    headers: { "request-id": requestID },
    path: "/delay/." + delay,
  };
  require("http")
    .get(request, (res) => {
      var body = "";
      res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });
      res.on("end", function () {
        cb(res, body);
      });
    })
    .end();
}

concurrentRequests(5);
function concurrentRequests(limit) {
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    sendRequest(i, function (res, body) {
      var reqID = JSON.parse(body).headers["Request-Id"];
      var sCode = res.statusCode;
      console.log("Concurrent Response #" + reqID + " returned a " + sCode);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You didnt add on("error") litener for http.get. JSON.parse also can throw an error, you must try...catch it